# Javascript filter HTML content to exclude italics tags and content

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently extracting html content from `ckeditor`. Normally it looks like

**Category 1**
**News 1 (link>** News content 
John: This is my comment 
**News 2 (link>** News content 
Mark: This is my comment

**Category 2**
**News 1 (link>** News content 
John: This is my comment 
**News 2 (link>** News content 
Mark: This is my comment

But the `ckeditor` return the unnecessary HTML code and this is what it is like

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> <td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <p style ="color:red">Category 1 </p>
           <p style ="color:black">
             <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 1 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
              <br>
              <i>John </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
           </p>
           <p style ="color:black">
             <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 2 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
              <br>
              <i>Mark </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
           </p>
         </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> <td>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <p style ="color:red">Category 2 </p>
           <p style ="color:black">
             <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 3 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
              <br>
              <i>John </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
           </p>
           <p style ="color:black">
             <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 4 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
              <br>
              <i>Mark </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
           </p>
         </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use an array to extract the information like this

var obj = { category 1: { News1: News1, News2: News 2 }, category 2: { News3: News 3, News4: News 4} };

I have used the javascript map function to extract the category name and news including the comment, any idea how can I use filter to exclude the italics part of HTML code?

This is what I have tried

```
  let doc = parser.parseFromString(this.text, 'text/html")
  let tableCon = doc.getElementByClassName ("tableclass")
  tableCon.map(element =>{
      let innerTable= Array.from(element.getElementbyTagName ('p'))
      categoryName = innerTable[0].innerText
        innerTable.shift();
        innerTable.map(ele =>{
          totalContent = ele.innerHTML
       }
     }
```

......

So I am able to get the category name and all content but couldn't filter the italics content

Comment: Try to get content inside <a> instead, getElementsByTagName('a') will be usefull

Comment: btw u sure this code works? even when I fix the countless syntax errors it just returns an empty array `[]`

Comment: @TheBombSquad, yes it is working. May be I have missed the classname for table but what I was showing was the structure.

Comment: ok.. I answered.. check it out >:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your code didn't work for me at all, so I just wrote from scratch.. also for each table(the top top 2 table elements that repeat the same structure going in) I just gave them a className called `tableClass`

As to how the code below works.. I made 2 functions, one that gets the stuff from each top top table, and the other that returns the data in your requested format(*THE SOLUTION*). Hoped this helped :D

```js
let tableCon = document.getElementsByClassName("tableClass")
function results(elem){
  let newsTitles=[]; let newsContents=[]
  for(let i=0;i<8;i++){elem=elem.children[0]}
  let category=elem.children[0].innerText
  for(let i=1;i<elem.children.length;i++){
    let element=elem.children[i]
    newsTitles.push(element.children[0].children[0].innerText)
    newsContents.push(element.children[1].innerText)
  }
  return [category,newsTitles,newsContents]
}

function newsObj(table){
  let obj={}
  for(let i=0;i<table.length;i++){
    let tempObj={}
    let [category,newsTitles,newsContents]=results(table[i])
    obj[category]=tempObj
    for(let j=0;j<newsTitles.length;j++){
      tempObj[newsTitles[j]]=newsContents[j]
      //change the above line to the commented line below to have stuff like "News 1" where stuff like "Content..." are
      //tempObj[newsTitles[j]]=newsTitles[j]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
console.log(newsObj(tableCon))
```

```html
<table class="tableClass">
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <p style ="color:red">Category 1 </p>
                <p style ="color:black">
                  <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 1 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
                  <br>
                  <i>John </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
               </p>
               <p style ="color:black">
                 <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 2 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
                  <br>
                  <i>Mark </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
               </p>
             </div>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
<table class="tableClass">
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>
              <p style ="color:red">Category 2 </p>
               <p style ="color:black">
                 <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 3 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
                  <br>
                  <i>John </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
               </p>
               <p style ="color:black">
                 <a href="abc.com"> <font>News 4 </font></a> <font>Content...</font>
                  <br>
                  <i>Mark </i><font><i>This is my comment </i></font> 
               </p>
             </div>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Now as to the fiddle you showed me, you placed the `tableClass` in places where it shouldn't be. Look at the example below(I didn't place it in EVERY table, only the "top top" ones)

I didn't need to add `newsTitle`, `newsContent` and `category` classNames all over the place, but **IF** you change your html layout again, and if the layout will change constantly(as in the HTML structure itself changing), yea, use classNames for them

```js
let tableCon = document.getElementsByClassName("MsoNormalTable")
function results(elem){
  let newsTitles=[]; let newsContents=[]
  for(let i=0;i<8;i++){elem=elem.children[0]}
  let category=elem.children[0].innerText
  elem=elem.parentNode
  for(let i=1;i<elem.children.length;i++){
    let element=elem.children[i]
    let text=element.children[0].children[0].innerText
    newsTitles.push(text)
    newsContents.push(element.innerText.substr(text.length))
  }
  let filter=(a)=>a.toLowerCase()!=a.toUpperCase()
  //filter out empty text(as you have html structures LIKE a newsTitle or a newsContent but EMPTY)
  newsTitles=newsTitles.filter(filter)
  newsContents=newsContents.filter(filter)
  return [category,newsTitles,newsContents]
}

function newsObj(table){
  let obj={}
  for(let i=0;i<table.length;i++){
    let tempObj={}
    let [category,newsTitles,newsContents]=results(table[i])
    obj[category]=tempObj
    for(let j=0;j<newsTitles.length;j++){
      tempObj[newsTitles[j]]=newsContents[j]
      //change the above line to the commented line below to have stuff like "News 1" where stuff like "Content..." are
      //tempObj[newsTitles[j]]=newsTitles[j]
    }
  }
  return obj
}
console.log(newsObj(tableCon))
```

```html
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640" style="width: 480pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-top: none; border-right: none; border-left: none; border-image: initial; border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding: 18.75pt 11.25pt;">
                <table class="MsoNormal" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="610" style="width: 457.5pt; padding: 0cm;">
                                <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">PC

                                        <o:p></o:p>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                        <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                                <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 12pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">
                                    <b>
                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">Brand1 </span>
                                    </b>
                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">is simply dummy</span>
                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">
                                        <a href="https://example.com/link.html" title="https://example.com/link.html">
                                            <span style="color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">text of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
                                        </a>
                                        <span style="background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"> text of the printing and typesetting industry</span>
                                        <br>
                                            <a href="mailto:hello@abc.com" title="mailto:hello@abc.com">
                                                <i>
                                                    <span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 10); background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">Abc:</span>
                                                </i>
                                            </a>&nbsp;

                                            <i>
                                                <span style="background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                            </i>
                                        </span>
                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
                                            <o:p></o:p>
                                        </span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                        <b>
                                            <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">Brand2 </span>
                                        </b>
                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                            <a href="https://example.com" title="https://example.com">
                                                <span style="color: black;"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                            <br>
                                                <br>
                                                </span>
                                                <b>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">Brand3 </span>
                                                </b>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">will </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <a href="https://example.com">
                                                        <span style="color: black;"> Lorem Ipsum has been the </span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;"> on 10 MAR</span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <o:p></o:p>
                                                </span>
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: start;"></p>
            <table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="640" style="width: 480pt;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-top: none; border-right: none; border-left: none; border-image: initial; border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(204, 204, 204); padding: 18.75pt 11.25pt;">
                            <table class="MsoNormal" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="610" style="width: 457.5pt; padding: 0cm;">
                                            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">CATEGORY2

                                                    <o:p></o:p>
                                                </span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
                                                </span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 5pt 12pt 0cm; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt;">
                                                <b>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">Bran3 </span>
                                                </b>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">has reportedly agreed to </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <a href="https://example.com">
                                                        <span style="color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">;  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <o:p></o:p>
                                                </span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 5pt 0.0001pt 0cm; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt;">
                                                <b>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">BRAND3 </span>
                                                </b>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">is </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <a href="https://example.com">
                                                        <span style="color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black; background-image: initial; background-position: initial; background-size: initial; background-repeat: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial;">  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <o:p></o:p>
                                                </span>
                                            </p>
                                            <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0.0001pt; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; line-height: 10.5pt; vertical-align: baseline;">
                                                <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                    <br>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <b>
                                                        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">BRAND4</span>
                                                    </b>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                        <a href="https://example.com">
                                                            <span style="color: black;">is looking at</span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: black;">  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</span>
                                                    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: rgb(255, 102, 0);">
                                                        <o:p></o:p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g0d6u5ex/ this is the actua data but not working

Comment: hm.. there seems to be a different html structure than the one u presented? not sure yet checking still...

Comment: ok for **SURE** there is a different html structure.. so why don't you put classNames specifically for `category`, `news` and `newsContent`? I'm gonna do that for your fiddle

Comment: @BinitaGyawali ok I SOLVED >:D